# Passing arguments when double tapping on images created from a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

The code below generates several "social media posts" with images nested within MDCards using a while loop. When the user double taps on one of the images, I want to be able to somehow know which of the images they double-tapped so that that image can call a function.

My intention is to create a mini internal blog for my app, when the user double-taps, for example, post #2 in the newsfeed, the "likes" for that post should increase.

Currently, in the code below, all the cards call the same function

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.utils.fitimage import FitImage
Window.size = (440, 760)

class ImageContainer(FitImage):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.is_double_tap:
                print("double tap")

class blog(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        blog_page = MDGridLayout(cols=1, spacing=40,  size_hint_y=None, padding=[20,])
        blog_page.bind(minimum_height=blog_page.setter('height'))

        count = 1
        while count <= 5:
            BlogPost = MDCard(elevation=1, radius=8, size_hint=(.9, None), height=300)
            BlogPost.add_widget(ImageContainer(source='data/assets/img/placeholder.jpg', radius=[8,]))
            blog_page.add_widget(BlogPost)
            count += 1

        blog = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1})
        blog.add_widget(blog_page)
        return blog

if __name__== '__main__':
    blog().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `self` argument of the `on_touch_down()` method identifies which `ImageContainer` was double tapped. You can see this if you modify that method:

```
class ImageContainer(FitImage):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.is_double_tap:
                print("double tap on", self, ", Image source:",  self.source)
```